# Audio manipulation with C++ (Android NDK)

Tags: c++, audio, mp3, wav, mixing

I have been developing a music editing Android app. I have written a considerable amount of code so far. However, due to audio latency issues encountered on the Android platform, I now realize that it is necessary to optimize my code using C/C++ (Android NDK) in order to manipulate audio files (Wav & MP3), and thus, hopefully, boost the app performance. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find concise resources dealing with the topic.

Could anybody post code examples on how to decode wav/mp3 files and mix them using C++? Any resource would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Usually file-reading does not cause latency issues; rather processing does. what are you trying to accomplish, exactly?

Comment: I would like to mix audio files using c++.

Comment: If you are having latency issues simply mixing two files you probably have a design/architecture issue. Switching to C++ might help, but if you have the same design, it might not.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a simple example](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/loading-a-wave-file-r709) for loading a wave file using C/C++.  It will help you get the ideas :)

As far as playing it .. you would probably be best off using [OpenSLES](http://www.khronos.org/registry/sles/) which is supported under the NDK on android.